# Show that each connected graph that is not a block has at least $2$ blocks, each containing exactly one cut-vertex.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that each connected graph that is not a block has at least $2$ blocks, each containing exactly one cut-vertex.

I know:

A block of graph $G$ is the maximal connected sub-graph of $G$ that has no cut-vertices.

So "connected graph that is not a block" means that graph has cut-vertices.

What can I say now?

Answer (score 1):

Given a graph $G$, we can associate to it a tree $T_G$, sometimes called its *block-cut tree*, in the following way: the vertex set of $T_G$ consists of one vertex for each block of $G$, as well as one vertex for each cut-vertex in $G$, and for each cut-vertex $v$ of $G$, we connect the vertex in $T_G$ corresponding to $v$ to the vertices corresponding to blocks containing $v$.

One can show that, as the naming suggests, $T_G$ is indeed a tree. A block that contains exactly one cut-vertex corresponds to a vertex of degree one in $T_G$; thus, your problem amounts to showing that $T_G$ has at least two leaves. This is clearly true under the assumption that $G$ itself was not $2$-connected (so that $T_G$ has at least two vertices).